# iSpeech SDK Android VerifyError

Tags: android, verifyerror, ispeech

I used [iSpeech Demo](http://www.ispeech.org/instructions/sampleprojects/android/fulldemo.html) to set up a test application with iSpeech SDK but it is giving me the following exception on which I am lost...

```
05-31 13:41:23.218: I/dalvikvm(271): Could not find method org.ispeech.SpeechSynthesis.getInstance, referenced from method org.ispeech.sdksample.TTSActivity.prepareTTSEngine
05-31 13:41:23.218: W/dalvikvm(271): VFY: unable to resolve static method 31: Lorg/ispeech/SpeechSynthesis;.getInstance (Landroid/app/Activity;)Lorg/ispeech/SpeechSynthesis;
05-31 13:41:23.218: D/dalvikvm(271): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 37 (Lorg/ispeech/error/InvalidApiKeyException;)
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x11
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): VFY:  rejected Lorg/ispeech/sdksample/TTSActivity;.prepareTTSEngine ()V
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0011
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): VFY:  rejected Lorg/ispeech/sdksample/TTSActivity;.prepareTTSEngine ()V
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): Verifier rejected class Lorg/ispeech/sdksample/TTSActivity;
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lorg/ispeech/sdksample/TTSActivity;)
05-31 13:41:23.228: D/AndroidRuntime(271): Shutting down VM
05-31 13:41:23.228: W/dalvikvm(271): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.VerifyError: org.ispeech.sdksample.TTSActivity
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-31 13:41:23.248: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thread on their forums seems to answer your question:
http://www.ispeech.org/forums/showthread.php/942-Verify-Error